# Bootstrap layout for Iframe breaks in print mode

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I have 2 plots (1st one is from iframe) that I want to be displayed on the same line in print mode. I use Bootstrap layout like this (React code)

```
<div style={{position:"relative"}}>
    <div className={'row'}>
    <div className={"col-lg-6"} id={'first'}>
       <iframe width="100%" frameBorder="0" height="400"
         src={"https://widget.finnhub.io/widgets/historical-eps?symbol=AAPL"}></iframe>
    </div>

    <div className={"col-lg-6"} id={'second'}>
       Second plot here (not from iframe)
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

During print mode, the 2 plots are in 2 separate lines.

[image]

After doing some research, I realized it has to do with the `col-lg` and the small screen size in print mode that makes the 2 plots in 2 separate lines. I change the `className` of `#first` and `#second` to `col-sm-6` and the result is like this.

[image]

The 2 plots are in the same line now but now there are 2 scrollbars for the iframe during the print mode. I tried using css to remove the scrollbar but didn't work. I have noticed the scrollbar only goes away if the `className` is `col-lg-6` or `col-xl-6`, but the 2nd plot will jump to the 2nd line with these classNames.

Is there any way I can display 2 plots in the same line in print mode without the annoying scrollbars in my iframe? Appreciate any help